# programmatically set UIView in XIB to hidden

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, xib

I have a `XIB` that is being used in two different views, since the views are very similar. In the `XIB` I have a small view that basically a vertical line that is acts as a separator. In one view I want the separator and in the other view I don't.

I have linked up the xib to its .h file and I can access the view through my other class.

**Cell.xib** - which has the view separator that I am talking about, which is UIView*cellSeparator
**HomeTableVC.h** this is where the xib is linked too. all the xib elements are linked this .h file.

**ChatTable.h/ChatTable.m** -

```
//ViewDidLoad
HomeTableVC* homeTable = [[HomeTableVC alloc] init];
homeTable.cellSeparator.hidden = YES;
```

Everything compiles and runs fine, but the `cellSeparator` don't get hidden.

I have tried putting it in `loadView`, `viewDidLoad`, I've tried calling it in the `mainThread`, but I can't seem to programmatically hide this UIView.

I have thought about just making to XIBs but that seems silly if I can just hide this one UIView and not have an almost duplicate xib.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: Another method I tried was setting a TAG for the cellSeparator and accessing the view via its tag, and it still does not hide.

Comment: did you checked the file oner and IBoutlet?

Comment: @ismail can the file owner be the only file to access that xib?

Comment: first check the IBOutlet connections

Comment: Everything seems to be linked up properly.

Comment: did you linked that view with some property and IBOutlet in .h file

Comment: can you show the .h file of  Cell.xib or HomeTableVC and screen shot of the xib wlll be better

Comment: Sorry, Everything was fine, except I was trying to set the UIView to hidden before the cell was drawn... =/ noob mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
HomeTableVC* homeTable = [[HomeTableVC alloc] init];
homeTable.cellSeparator.hidden = YES;
```

You are actually not hiding the separator from your `IBoutlet` (which connects XIB component to class file) but creating new instance of `HomeTableVC` which does't have access for XIB component.

Comment: Just do what is not been done, hide component from outlet. And the problem will be solved.